# jquery update dom on ajax complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having some issues where the dom is only updated once the $.each loop has completed.

On my page I have a number of divs which when looped over has a orange color applied to it, when the data is posted to the server if the response is 200 the div color is changed to green otherwise it is changed to red.

The issue with the script is that the dom isn't updated, the color is always orange/pending. If I remove that bit of code then the items do turn green/complete, but only after each ajax call has completed.

How can I get the dom to update after each $.ajax call? Thanks

```
    $.each(csv_ids , function( i , val ) {

        $('#item_' + val).addClass('csv_pending_item_pending');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/foo' ,
            type: 'POST' ,
            async: false,
            data: { csvID : val } ,
            error : function() {
                console.log('error');
            },
            success: function(data) {

                $('#loop_upload_item').html(val);

                console.log(data)

                if(data.response == '200') {
                    $('#item_' + val).addClass('csv_pending_item_complete');
                    console.log('#item_' + val + ' good')
                }else{
                    $('#item_' + val).addClass('csv_pending_item_error');
                }

            }
        }); // ajax
    }); // each
```

Comment: add async: false to your ajax

Comment: Please stop using `async: false`.   Your users will appreciate that you don't lock up your browser during multiple ajax calls.

Comment: I don't want to run all the items at once, I need to stagger the upload process.

Comment: Well then only start the AJAX request for an item after the request for the previous one has finished … (Or something like that – hard to be more specific, if the question itself is that vague. We don’t know what yu are _actually_ trying to implement here, so we can hardly make suggestions as to what might be the best in regard to user experience etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will only repaint when your javascript stops executing. Because you're not using asynchronous requests it doesn't stop and the repaint only happens at the very end, after all the requests have completed.

If you remove `async: false,` I would expect it to work as you want. However, as you say you want to stagger the upload process you need to trigger the next upload to start when the previous one completes.

Something like the following should work. You'll see that we look through each id and create a function to do the upload for that id. At the end of the success function we call the next function in the chain.

```
var upload_func= function () { };
for(var val in csv_ids) {
    var next_func = upload_func;
    upload_func= function() {
        $('#item_' + val).addClass('csv_pending_item_pending');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/foo' ,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { csvID : val } ,
            error : function() {
                console.log('error');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#loop_upload_item').html(val);

                console.log(data)

                if(data.response == '200') {
                    $('#item_' + val).addClass('csv_pending_item_complete');
                    console.log('#item_' + val + ' good')
                }else{
                     $('#item_' + val).addClass('csv_pending_item_error');
                }
                next_func();
            }
       }
    }
}

upload_func();
```